# Список всех файлов в директории кроме "exe"-шников

Tags: c#

Как получить список всех файлов в директории с вычетом "exe"-шников?

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(dir + @"\", ??? ЧТОБ ТУТ УКАЗАТЬ ???);
```

Comment: Что бы конец не был равен .exe. Что сложного?

Comment: `var files = Directory.GetFiles(dir + @"\").Where(x=>!x.EndsWith(".exe"));`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ чтоб то же самое в виде string[] получить можно как то?

Comment: `.toArray()` в конец.

Comment: А вообще я бы на вашем месте не через `GetFiles` получал бы файлы, а рекурсивно, например [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14305616/6808809). Там вы можете банальным if отсечь все .exe файлы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как один из вариантов решения данной задачи, это отфильтровать полученный массив с помощью [Where](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) (LINQ):

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(dir + @"\").Where(x=>!x.EndsWith(".exe")).ToArray();
```

То есть мы убрали `searchPattern` у `GetFiles`, он нам вернет все найденные файлы, далее с помощью [Where](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) мы берем все элементы, окончание которых не равно `.exe`, ну и для удобства формируем обратно `string[]` при помощи [ToArray()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.toarray).

P.S. Как правильно заметил @tym32167, расширение лучше получать предназначенными для этого методами, например [Path.GetExtension](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension).

---

Вообще я бы на вашем месте наверно написал бы свой метод, который бы рекурсивно составлял список файлов с необходимыми нам фильтрами. За основу можно взять к примеру [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305581/method-to-get-all-files-within-folder-and-subfolders-that-will-return-a-list/14305616#14305616) вариант и тогда при добавление в лист просто сделать обычный `if`.

Comment: У Path вроде метод ест для получения расширения файла, наверное лучше им воспользоваться

Comment: @tym32167 Я бы лично перевел все в FileInfo, больше дальнейших возможностей, ну а так да, вы правы. Вообще, смотря на [исходники](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,300) данного метода, я бы сказал что он просто берет из строки последние символы с точкой, проверка на окончание строки по сути должна работать также хорошо, да и короче все это получается.

Comment: Результат то да, будет тот же самый. Я просто за то, чтобы максимально использовать фреймворк, так как хз сработает ли такой фокус на других платформах или в будущем — чем самому считывать расширение, пусть лучше фреймворк это делает за вас. Хотя это, конечно, правило не строгое и абсолютно не обязательное